# Apply an onclick event to Kendo Gantt chart task

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'd like to apply an onclick event to the task div generated by a Kendo Gantt chart. This is the code I have tried:

```
$(document).on 'click', '.k-task', ->
#  do something
```

I believe that this onclick is being overridden or hidden somehow by Kendo's built-in onclick for tasks. Unfortunately it doesn't seem like there is a click event in the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the entire event chain is handled by kendo itself, you can use Gantt `edit` event, for double click.

> Fired when the user starts task edit upon double click on a cell.
>
> The event handler function context (available via the this keyword)
>   will be set to the widget instance.

Code:

```
  edit: function(e) {
    alert("Editing task: "+e.task.title);
  },
```

Ref: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/gantt#events-edit